# How to create a non cancellable event with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a pub/sub framework that is being used on several installs.
The framework uses `jQuery().trigger()` and `jQuery().on()` and works fine on most installs.

But, there are some installs where the system breaks, probably because there is some code that stops propagation.

Using plain JavaScript I could create events which are not cancellable like so:

```js
const myEvent = new Event("customLoad", {cancelable: false})
document.dispatchEvent(myEvent)
```

I'd like to keep using jQuery if possible. Is there a way to also make a jQuery event non-cancellable somehow?

I've tried `.triggerHandler()`. But it doesn't bubble up as it should in my case.

So in my case I use the pub/sub like this:

```js
jQuery(document).trigger("customLoad")

jQuery(window).on("customLoad")
```

Is it possible that some `stopPropagation()` is interfering?
And could the simple solution be to change `window` to `document` in `jQuery(window).on("customLoad")`

Edit:

I found what the issue was. The theme developer of the WordPress site with the issue loads jQuery one more time, even though WordPress already loads a current version of jQuery. And the theme loads the jQuery after my code registers the events.

I'm not exactly sure what happens when jQuery is loaded again after my events have been registered. But I guess some references get overwritten.

Comment: I think you might be confusing `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`, I don't believe the cancelable status of an event affects wether or not that event can travel up to parent elements.

Comment: @DBS: I just played around with https://domevents.dev/ and it found the same result. Making an event non-cancellable will not overcome if propagation is stopped. So there is no way to work around `stopPropagation()`?

Comment: It's difficult to give any detailed examples without knowing what your code/event does, but: If you listen for the event on the element that it's triggered on (rather than, e.g. `document`) it won't need to propagate to reach your listener, and shouldn't be affected by listeners attached to parent elements.

Comment: That event **is** on the `document`, like in the example above.

Comment: I just added more context. Could the simple solution be to change `window` to `document` in `jQuery(window).on("customLoad")`?

Comment: Even though it is bad coding style you can mix standard javascript with jquery.

Comment: I found the issue, which was not related to event propagation at all, and added the explanation to my question. 
I guess there is no real answer for this and I probably should delete my question. Right?